# Jquery ajax, when periodicaly called, doesnt work on IE8

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer

I am currently doing the same ajax request using jQuery every 2sec. For some reason, on IE8 it only work the first time. Each following request automatically seems to go to the onSuccess function, with the same result as the first request.

The same code work perfeclty on FF3 and Chrome.

Is anybody aware of that bug and how to hack around it?
Or am I simply doing something wrong?

Comment: Can you post some code please? It's hard for us to see a problem without it.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

IE has a caching feature... it's possible that it has just cached your request. Make sure you append something like a random number to your query string, like so:

```
var url = "/yoururl.html";
url = url + "&random=" + Math.random();
```

Comment: An alternative solution is to simply use POST; POST requests shall not be cached (sayeth the spec).

Answer (score 6):

Just so you know `$.ajax` has a `cache` attribute that, when set to false does exactly what Jason is doing, namely, includes a random parameter that means no requests get cached.  It's a little more elegant than doing it yourself

Answer (score 0):

I have just encountered the same thing and have fixed it by setting the "cache" property of your ajax function call to false.

```
        $.ajax({
            url: "/ws/inventory/checkavailability/",
            async: false,
            dataType: 'json',
            cache:false,
            success: function (data) {
                //so something interesting
            }, error: function (error) {
                //display error?
            }
        });
```

Comment: this might be a double, I did not notice the answer of brad :)

anyways here is a sample code.