# ajax not firing webmethod sometimes

Tags: jquery, ajax, webmethod

I'm calling a webmethod from jquery/ajax. Sometimes my webmethod gets called, other times it doesn't. I'm passing the same arguments every time (the digit 1 and a short string of text). I've also created handlers to catch error and show codes when the ajax call is complete. Even when it doesn't call my webmethod, the status is "success." Any ideas?

The jquery:

```
var txt = $(ta).val();

$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: 'Default.aspx/AddThread',
    contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
    data: JSON.stringify({ forumId: id, comment: txt }),
    dataType: 'json',
    error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
        alert("status: " + textStatus);
        alert("errorThrown: " + errorThrown);
    },
    complete: function (jqXHR, textStatus) {
        alert("status: " + textStatus);
    }
});
```

The C#:

```
[WebMethod]
public static void AddThread(int forumId, string comment)
{
    DataAccess.AddNewThread(forumId, comment);
}
```

Comment: It actually seems to work consistently in IE. I get the intermittent behavior in Chrome.

Answer (score 1):

my guess is that it's just not working in IE. If this is the case, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1190318/jquery-ajax-when-periodicaly-called-doesnt-work-on-ie8/1190335#1190335).

Answer (score 1):

If your parameters are the same as a previous call it wont invoke the code

```
    //i.e.  
    AddThread(42, "Hello World");

    //then later you also call
    AddThread(42, "Hello World");

    //the web method wont invoke any code it will just return the cached result.`
```

to stop this behavior you can set CacheDuration to 0 so that it no longer saves the result

```
[WebMethod(CacheDuration=0)]
public static void AddThread(int forumId, string comment)
{
    DataAccess.AddNewThread(forumId, comment);

}
```

Comment: That shouldn't be an issue since the requests are POSTs and he doesn't care about the (empty) response.

Comment: Unfortunately, this didn't do the trick. Even the FIRST call I made upon running the web app this morning didn't hit my break point! The second and third calls did, and the fourth call didn't.

Comment: Are you able to find your ajax calls using the "Network Tab" of "Developer Tools" in chrome (see the [screenshot](http://i1-news.softpedia-static.com/images/news2/The-Google-Chrome-Developer-Tools-Improves-Network-Info-and-CSS-Editing-2.png))? 

Are you making successful posts but receiving no response?

Is the client and service running locally on your machine?

Comment: A little more info on my system: Windows 7 & Visual Studio 2010. I'm just using Visual Studio's web server. Everything is local. I made the call and Chrome's debugging tools make it look like my method was called but it never hit my breakpoint. How can I upload a screenshot?

Comment: did you try using the "scripts" tab of developer tools to debug your ajax call in that browser?  If you're right about it being browser specific you are likely to see the problem there... your code looks correct to me, I've never heard of a xhr only working intermittently in one browser.